# Amazon s3cmd ls latest/random 10 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to see n random objects (or the latest n objects) in a S3 bucket containing billions of objects. How can I do that without degrading the performance of an EC2 instance or messing up the mentioned S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet I think is going to be to maintain a database, perhaps in Dynamodb or RDS, with the metadata about your s3 objects. Perform your queries there, and then use the results to locate the 'n' random/newest files.

With  lot less objects, you could list all of the files, and then randomize or determine the newest 'on-the-fly', but with billions of objects your performance will suffer if you try to scan the objects.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that this is not my own bucket and I do not have any metadata about objects in this bucket. I was hoping that Amazon has provisioned such a situation and has offered some argument with the `s3cmd ls` command to see the n recently added objects for example.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I think probably there is no out of the box way for that purpose. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think there is an 'out of the box' solution for this - you are correct.